# Passing a path from Bash to Python on Windows automatically tries to convert it to an absolute path - is there a way to prohibit that?

Tags: python, windows, bash, path

I am trying to pass a path to a Python script as an argument using `sys.argv[x]`. However the passing of said path from Bash to Python seems to convert it to a different path. Why is that?
Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
path='/var/log'
echo "$path"
python script.py "$path"
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
logPath = sys.argv[1]
print(logPath)
```

Output:

```
/var/log/
C:/Program Files/Git/var/log/
```

Comment: Are you using git bash?

Comment: Yep. Git bash on windows.

Comment: It looks like git bash is trying to be smart, and is force-interpreting strings as paths. We "know" that `/var/log/` is a path, but strictly speaking it's just an 8 character string. And on Windows, `/something` when used in `argv[]` is by convention a flag, not a path.

Comment: Is there a way to force git bash to not interprete strings?

Comment: I could just append a second / in front of the path and the remove it again in my python script, but that looks more like a hack than anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did some further investigation and found out that this is a known "feature" of `mingw` trying to be smart. To fix it I added the following `export` to my bash script:

```
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
```

You can read more about this on git:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24029